# Should we use ng-blur with ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a concern with AngularJS's `ng-change` and `ng-blur`, so I would like to confirm with an expert what is the right way to use them when we update a form value.

1. I have a dropdown in the below code, and I want to execute `overrideBusinessDec()` when the user changes the dropdown's value. With the current implementation, because of `ng-blur`, it's happening when we click away from the form. I can make a quick fix by removing `ng-blur` from the field, and it will work as expected.
2. Another scenario: When you are in an edit state, it populates values, but does not enable the form if I don't add `ng-blur` on the field. I don't know how to fix that.

Is there a solution that can take care of both problems?

```
<!-- main.html -->
<div>
    <select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-value-field="'id'"
        k-data-text-field="'text'" k-option-label="'Select'"
        k-data-source="ctrlEffOptions"
        ng-disabled="!processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingComputeKey"
        ng-model="processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingOverrideKey"
        ng-change="overrideBusinessDec()" id="controlEffBusiness" required ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-change` fires when the value of the element changes, so it's a good choice for you dropdown. It it also a good choice for a text field when you want something to happen as you type, like an autocomplete. If you want to wait for the user to be finished and leave the text field, use `on-blur`, which fires when the field loses focus.

`on-blur` doesn't affect whether your form fields are enabled. You must be doing something else to cause that.

Comment: this isn't quite right. `change` won't happen while typing in text field...only when blur occurs and there is a value change

Comment: `ng-change` fires with each keystroke because it's triggered by the `ng-model` change. Check out the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and [proof of concept](http://plnkr.co/edit/MqoZ619uhYgPmd1RaiZy).

Comment: my bad... was thinking about normal dom change events

Comment: Thanks all for the response i got enough information to understand ng-blur and ng-change.